# MousePressed Event for multiple labels

Tags: c#

I'm doing some kind of a pixel film editor and my problem there is that I am using Labels which I have to click individually to change their color, I would like to change the color by holding down the mouse button and just hovering above the Label.

Is there any Event or such to do so? I didn't find one. At the moment I am using Mouse_Down.

[A look on the Editor](https://i.gyazo.com/793e91ef49bfbbf78e3ab2f62f45aa28.gif)

my Mouse_Down Event:

```
private void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var ActiveLabel = sender as Label;
    if (ActiveLabel != null)
    {
        ActiveLabel.BackColor = ActiveColor.BackColor;
    }
}
```

So I want it like on GIMP or stuff, to not click any single "pixel" but instead click and hold the mouse button and move it around and color all pixels I move over whilst my mouse is pressed.

Comment: I can't use a graphics object in my case, and for sure Mouse_Enter and Mouse_Leave itself isn't bad, but I do also need to check for a pressed Mouse Button then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the idea:

You have a flag (boolean) which indicates whether the user is currently painting or not. If the mouse hovers over a label (event [MouseEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx)), you check whether it should be painted or not. If it shall be painted, you apply the code you already have.

```
bool paintmode = false;

// Assign this to all labels, since you don't know
// where the user will start painting
private void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   paintmode = true;
}

// Make sure you assign this to all items, even the Form
// as you'll never know where the user will release the mouse
private void Mouse_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   paintmode = false;
}

// Assign this only to labels which can get painted
private void Mouse_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (paintmode)
    {
        var ActiveLabel = sender as Label;
        if (ActiveLabel != null)
        {
            ActiveLabel.BackColor = ActiveColor.BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With Mouse_Down and Mouse_Up it doesn't work as intended, but I will allow to change to paint mode with a double click or something. So thanks a lot!